# Product of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ and $v$ be real harmonic functions on a unit disk, and $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk. 
If $|f(z)|^2$ is harmonic, what can you say about $f$?

Answer: that $f$ is also harmonic.

Under what condition, $uv$ is harmonic? 
Answer: only if $u+icv$ is analytic for some real $c$

Is the condition necessary if $u$ and $v$ are polynomials?

Answer:no, since polynomials are always analytic?

Am I on the right track here? 
Any feedback would help.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one you can derive that $f$ is constant.

For the second one: Note that if $f$ is holomorphic so is $f^2$ and the imaginary part of a holomorphic function is harmonic.

Comment: so you mean one part must be harmonic and the other holomorphic so that their product is harmonic?